# Issue With Javascript / Jquery Dropdown Menu In Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

So I have some leftover code from a previous developer that essentially creates a multi-level dependent dropdown menu. You pick an option from dropdown Box A, and then options appear in dropdown Box B that relate specifically to Box A, and then after choosing one of those, an option specific to your choice in Box B appears in the third and final dropdown.

This works perfectly In Google Chrome & in Firefox, but it doesn't work at all in Safari. No matter what your choice, all of the options for all of the choices always appear in Box B and Box C.

I've looked everywhere and all over this site but haven't been able to find any solutions that relate to my situation. Ideally we want this to work in all three of the listed browsers, but none of my efforts have worked (I have at best a basic knowledge here).

The page code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/specstyle.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/power.js"/></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="formname" name="formname" method="post" 
action="submitform.asp">
  <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <td width="41%" align="right" valign="middle">Box A</td>
      <td width="59%" align="left" valign="middle">
        <select name="powcat1" id="powcat1">
          <option value="">Please Select</option>
          <option value="Option1">510</option>
          <option value="Option2">750</option>
          <option value="Option3">850</option>
          <option value="Option4">1000</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <form id="formname1" name="formname1" method="post" action="submitform.asp">
      <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="middle">BOX B : </td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
          <select disabled="disabled" id="powcat2" name="powcat2">
            <option class="label" value>Please Select</option>
            <option rel="Option1" value="A2">2</option>
            <option rel="Option1" value="B4">4</option>
            <option rel="Option2" value="C6">6</option>
            <option rel="Option2" value="D8">8</option>
            <option rel="Option3" value="E10">10</option>
            <option rel="Option3" value="F12">12</option>
            <option rel="Option4" value="G14">14</option>
            <option rel="Option4" value="H16">16</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <form id="formname2" name="formname2" method="post" action="submitform.asp">
        <tr>
          <td align="right" valign="middle">BOX C: </td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle">
            <select disabled="disabled" id="powcat3" name="powcat3">
              <option class="label" value>Please Select</option>
          <option rel="A2" value="http://www.website.com/1">A</option>
          <option rel="B4" value="http://www.website.com/2">B</option>
          <option rel="C6" value="http://www.website.com/3">C</option>
          <option rel="D8" value="http://www.website.com/4">D</option>
          <option rel="E10" value="http://www.website.com/5">E</option> 
          <option rel="F12" value="http://www.website.com/6">F</option>
          <option rel="G14" value="http://www.website.com/7">G</option>
          <option rel="H16" value="http://www.website.com/8">H</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" valign="middle">
        <button type="button" id="myButton" disabled>Submit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the CSS I am using:

```
#powcat2 option {
  display: none;
}

#powcat2 option.label {
  display: block;
}

#powcat3 option {
  display: none;
}

#powcat3 option.label {
  display: block;
}

#myButton {
    background-color: #EC2C03;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
}
```

And the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $grigg = $("#powcat1"),
  $subgrigg = $("#powcat2"),
  $neco = $("#powcat3"),
  $myButton = $("#myButton");

$grigg.on("change", function() {
  var _rel = $(this).val();
  $subgrigg.find("option").attr("style", "");
  $subgrigg.val("");
  $neco.val("");
  $myButton.prop("disabled", true);
  if (!_rel) {
    $subgrigg.prop("disabled", true);
    $neco.prop("disabled", true);
    return;
  }
  $subgrigg.find("[rel=" + _rel + "]").show();
  $subgrigg.prop("disabled", false);
});

$subgrigg.on("change", function() {
  var _rel = $(this).val();
  $neco.find("option").attr("style", "");
  $neco.val("");
  $myButton.prop("disabled", true)
  if (!_rel) {
    $neco.prop("disabled", true);
    return;
  }
  $neco.find("[rel=" + _rel + "]").show();
  $neco.prop("disabled", false);
});

$neco.on("change", function() {
  var _rel = $(this).val();
  if (!_rel) {
    $myButton.prop("disabled", true);
    return;
  }
  $myButton.prop("disabled", false); // allow the user to submit
});

$myButton.on("click", function() {
    console.log("Send me to: " + $neco.val());
    window.open( $neco.val() );
  });
});
```

Despite my best efforts I've made no headway on this... not really sure why it works so well on some browsers but not on Safari...

Comment: Probably not THE issue, but AN issue you're having is in the #powcat3 select. Take a look at the values of the options. Specifically, at the close quote on the values on those options...

Comment: Thanks for catching that - fixed it. Isn't the issue though - I simplified things for here as the actual URLs are extremely long and accidentally deleted the quotation in the process.

Comment: Sorry, that was my one-trick pony. I'm not running safari on this machine, so...